# No valid crumb was included in the request - Jenkins 403

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, ubuntu-16.04, jenkins-cli

My Crumb.sh file is :

```
    crumb=$(curl -u "jenkins:pwd" -s 'http://yuvi_jenkins:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
    echo $crumb
    curl -u "jenkins:pwd" -H "$crumb" -X POST http://yuvi_jenkins:8080/job/ansible-project/build?delay=0sec
```

The Output I get is :

```
Jenkins-Crumb:d3950e9f61bc9dd88fba532c17dba1ce220be11b92d78e720464afd38021a3fb


<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 403 No valid crumb was included in the request</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /job/ansible-project/build. Reason:
<pre> No valid crumb was included in the request</pre></p><hr><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>

</body>
</html>
```

Solutions that I have tried :

```
1) Probably you are accessing jenkins by proxy server, please do following

    Go to "Global Security Settings"
    Check "Enables the Compatibilty Mode for proxies".
    Restart

2) To resolve this issue I unchecked "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" in jenkins.com/configureSecurity section.
```

I have tried the above solutions but still I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Jenkins Documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/upgrade-guide/2.176/#SECURITY-626), crumbs are now only valid for the web session in which they were created. To get around this you can store your cookies when making the crumb request, and then use those stored cookies when making subsequent API calls. So your script would become:

```
crumb=$(curl --cookie-jar ./cookie -u "jenkins:pwd" -s 'http://yuvi_jenkins:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
curl --cookie ./cookie -u "jenkins:pwd" -H "$crumb" -X POST http://yuvi_jenkins:8080/job/ansible-project/build?delay=0sec
```

Alternatively the documentation I linked suggests setting the system property `hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer.EXCLUDE_SESSION_ID` to `true`, or using the Strict Crumb Issuer Plugin to change crumb validation to use something like time rather than session ID

Thanks to https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2067#issuecomment-544993648 for helping me solve the same problem